# Unscoped work in rails console but not work in controller action

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have model with default_scope:

```
class Campaign < ActiveRecord::Base
  default_scope where("campaigns.status != ?", "archive")
end
```

Then I need disable this scope in show action:

```
@campaign = Campaign.unscoped.find(params[:id])
```

But I see `Couldn't find Campaign with id=1 [WHERE (campaigns.status != 'archive')]`

Then I tried the same solution in rails console:

```
 Campaign.unscoped.find(1)
 SELECT `campaigns`.* FROM `campaigns` WHERE `campaigns`.`id` = 1 LIMIT 1
```

And all works fine, what I doing wrong in controller?

**UPDATE:**

Campaign.unscoped{
}

Did not work too. It seems @campaign determined elsewhere and earlier, because I delete all rows from my show action and now it looks like:

```
def show
end
```

And I am still getting this error: `Couldn't find Campaign with id=1 [WHERE (campaigns.status != 'archive')]`

I find out this tricks in `load_and_authorize_resource`, but how can I fix it?

Comment: Is there any trace with the error message?

Comment: Smth wrong with `load_and_authorize_resource`

Comment: I think I need only `authorize_resource`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like what you have would work fine, according to the documentation. However, it is mentioned [here](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/unscoped/class) that it is recommended to use the block form of unscoped. You might give that a try and see if it resolves the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Ref [this](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/unscoped/class)

```
Campaign.unscoped {
  Campaign.find(params[:id]) 
}
```